# Configuring Express and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a simple Angular/Express todo-list app, and I ran into quite a bit of trouble. It's still in the works, but when I ran the code below on localhost:3000 I ended up getting {{ thing }} literally printed in the webpage.

My file paths are:

- app

  - js

    - app.js
  - index.html
- node_modules (here lies angular, express, etc)
- index.js
- package.json

Here is my code for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='testApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular-Express Test App</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/app.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Item</td>
                <td>Remove</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
                <td><a href="#"></a>Done?</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code for index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000); //yes I plan to deploy to OpenShift
app.set('ipaddr', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1");


app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html', res);
});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log('Express server listening on  IP: ' + app.get('ipaddr') + ' and port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

And app.js:

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('TestCtrl', [$scope, function ($scope) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.items = ["foo", "bar"];
    }]);
```

Here's a screenshot of what I see, though there really isn't much in it that I haven't mentioned already...: http://puu.sh/gyhjT/684fa116f7.png

I spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure out what went wrong, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: open browser console and take a look at error messages

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjhack/mgf4ohq5/1/ have just tried this and it works. Like previous comment check console and you might have an error on the server side

Comment: are you sure your pathing is correct? seems like your controller is not loaded. I tried in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GIP5zAIPYDtB4LOJSBGK?p=preview and it works...

Comment: Mido22's solution worked for me. However, before then I didn't get any error message in console, even through nodemon in debug mode, so that was pretty strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few mistakes in your code,

first , the major one, you are directing every request to index page, so no way to get `js/app.js`

so change:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html', res);
});
```

to:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html', res);
});


app.get('/js/:file', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/js/'+req.params.file, res);
});
```

next is, `ngRoute` and `$scope` mistake, `ngRoute` is not part of `angular.min.js`, you have to include it seperately, for now, i just changed your `js/app.js` and it works for me

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        'use strict';
        $scope.items = ["foo", "bar"];
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I applied the changes that you had, but the page is still printing out as {{ item }} like in the puush link I have above.

Comment: what is your console saying? also, are the files in the right location, now your html must be in `project_root/app/` folder and `app.js` in `project_root/js/` folder.

Comment: Nothing. I didn't get any errors, and from running with `DEBUG=express:* nodemon index.js` it didn't give any errors. GET was successful for /app/js/app.js.

EDIT: I moved the files to the right directory, and now it's working. Thanks so much!

Comment: changed logic slightly, check now

Answer (score 0):

remove ['ngRoute'] because you don't use it. If you want to use, please include angular-route.js in head

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried mido22's solution, which included taking out 'ngRoute', but that didn't fix the issue. Do you have any suggestions?